# \str_case:nnF not finding match

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3

I have written a command using expl3 that is supposed to behave differently if the optional argument is specified as * or **. The command is intended for a math environment, and is supposed to render the second parameter with an upright underset depending on the first parameter. I see three problems in the behavior of this command:

1. The * and ** are not recognized
2. An extraneous hyphen (-) is displayed
3. An extraneous quote (") is displayed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Render underscored with some variation of strict
\NewDocumentCommand{\strict}{O{strict} m}
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {\str_item:nn {#1} {-1}} {-}
      {
        \show_strict:nn {{#1}strict} {#2}
      }
      {
        \show_strict:nn {#1} {#2}
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_strict:nn #1 #2
  {
   \msg_term:n {show_strict \ P1 \ = \ #1}
   \msg_term:n {show_strict \ P2 \ = \ #2}
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpb_str {#2}
    \msg_term:n {\l_tmpa_str =  \l_tmpa_str}
    \str_case:nnF {\l_tmpa_str}
      {
        {
          {*}
          {  \underset {\mathrm{(semi-strict,strict)}} {#2} }
        }
        {
          {**}
          { \underset {\mathrm{semi-strict (strict)}} {#2} }
        }
      }
      {
        \underset {\mathrm{\l_tmpa_str}} {\l_tmpb_str}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Test $\strict{{default}}$ \\*
      expect underset with upright "strict" 
\item Test $\strict[semi-]{{hyphen}}$
      expect underset with upright "semi-strict"
\item Test $\strict[*]{{star}}$
      expect underset with upright "(semi-strict,strict)"
\item Test $\strict[**]{{starstar}}$
      expect underset with upright "semi-strict (strict)"
\end{enumerate}
\foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't want to output `\str_...` variables here, that cause the `-` -- use `\tl_...` variables for the output and the `\str_case:nnF` is wrongly setup, in my point of view

Comment: Why not using a `\NewDocumentCommand{ssO{strict}m}` - approach, leaving the 'tricky' `*` handling to the features of `xparse`

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: 1) You have an extra `}` in the definition of `\show_strict:nn`. 2) It's not a good idea to edit your question asking something else, as may invalidate the answers. The best approach is to ask a new question.

Comment: @I want * and ** as alternatives to the text string, i.e., \strict [foo]{bar}, \strict [*]{bar} or \strict [**]{bar}, as they all specify what to underset foo with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the syntax for `\str_case:nnF` wrong; the first argument is the string to look for matches; the second argument should be of the form

```
{<string-a>}{<code>}
{<string-b>}{<code>}
...
```

and you have additional braces that are wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Render underscored with some variation of strict
\NewDocumentCommand{\strict}{O{strict} m}
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {\str_item:nn {#1} {-1}} {-}
      {
        \show_strict:nn {{#1}strict} {#2}
      }
      {
        \show_strict:nn {#1} {#2}
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_strict:nn #1 #2
  {
   \iow_term:n {show_strict ~ P1 ~ = ~ #1}
   \iow_term:n {show_strict ~ P2 ~ = ~ #2}
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
       {*}  { \underset {\textup{(semi-strict,~strict)}} {#2} }
       {**} { \underset {\textup{semi-strict~(strict)}} {#2} }
      }
      {
        \underset {\textup{#1}} {#2}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Test $\strict{{default}}$ \\*
      expect underset with upright "strict" 
\item Test $\strict[semi-]{{hyphen}}$
      expect underset with upright "semi-strict"
\item Test $\strict[*]{{star}}$
      expect underset with upright "(semi-strict,strict)"
\item Test $\strict[**]{{starstar}}$
      expect underset with upright "semi-strict (strict)"
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Rather than `\mathrm` you should use `\textup` (the hyphens would be minus signs otherwise and spaces would be ignored).

Here's the console output:

```
*************************************************
* show_strict P1 = strict
*************************************************
*************************************************
* show_strict P2 = {default}
*************************************************
*************************************************
* show_strict P1 = {semi-}strict
*************************************************
*************************************************
* show_strict P2 = {hyphen}
*************************************************
*************************************************
* show_strict P1 = *
*************************************************
*************************************************
* show_strict P2 = {star}
*************************************************
*************************************************
* show_strict P1 = **
*************************************************
*************************************************
* show_strict P2 = {starstar}
*************************************************
```

Comment: How did you avoid the "! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
<recently read> ##
                  
l.42         \underset {\textup{#1}} {#2}" message?

Comment: @shmuel Do you get it with my code? I don't.

Comment: @shmuel Check your braces. You have a `}` too much.

Comment: @egreg, sorry again, you can update this response...just in order to keep the forum updated.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Thanks for the search!

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpb_str {#2}
```

you are setting the variables to TeX strings, removing the meaning from the tokens. In particular, `{` and `}` cease to be 'special', and come out as the 'random' quote mark/hyphen you are seeing. In your example, there's no reason to store these at all, but if you do, use a `tl`.

The second issue is

```
\str_case:nnF {\l_tmpa_str}
```

which compares *exactly* the text `\l_tmpa_str` with each case. They never match, so you get the `F` branch. You want to look at the text *itself*, easiest with

```
\str_case:nnF {#2}
```

or if you *really* want to store it, perhaps

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { V }

...

\str_case:VnF \l_tmpb_str
```

to access the *value* of the variable. Again, I suspect you want a token list test here, not a string one:

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {#2}
\tl_case:NnF \l_tmpb_tl
```

although as previously-mentioned, I don't see the need to store the input.